# Viewmodel Parameter specified as non-null comes back as null

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, rx-java

when I call my viewmodel it says that my parameter comes back as null even though the api call works so im wondering is the mistake happening in my viewmodel?

My viewmodel

```
class HomeFragmentVM(

    private val spManager: SPManager,
    private val repository: Repository
) : AbstractViewModel() {

    private val washingMachine = MutableLiveData<Post>()


    fun getWashingMachines() {
        launch {
            repository.getPost()
                .doOnSubscribe {

                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    washingMachine.value = it
                    spManager.saveTitleID(it.title)
                }, {
                })
        }
    }

}
```

The debug log:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter title
        at com.invenium.jlp_android_test.utils.SPManager.saveTitleID(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.invenium.jlp_android_test.functionalities.Home.HomeFragmentVM$getWashingMachines$1.invoke$lambda-1(HomeFragmentVM.kt:32)
        at com.invenium.jlp_android_test.functionalities.Home.HomeFragmentVM$getWashingMachines$1.lambda$UfyFFA37mNg1-E8x0CGZ3EyBoEY(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.invenium.jlp_android_test.functionalities.Home.-$$Lambda$HomeFragmentVM$getWashingMachines$1$UfyFFA37mNg1-E8x0CGZ3EyBoEY.accept(Unknown Source:4)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:63)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:81)
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:119)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The model:

```
data class Post(
    @SerializedName("products")
    var data: List<Data>,
    @SerializedName("productId")
    var productid: Int,
    @SerializedName("title")
    var title: String
)
```

The model has been a little shortened as some model as not been used yet.

Comment: Please share the model as well

Comment: @Jaymin I have added it now :)

Comment: Initialize title para with nullable or declare all the param nullable. it will fix your issue.

Comment: Do i initalize it in the viewmodel as nullable? @Jaymin

Answer (score 0):

Set default value for title like this:

- @SerializedName("title")
  var title: String = ""

after that , if your problem solved , check why title return null

Comment: This won't work, because Gson ignores it as it's instantiating the object through reflection.

Comment: yep this doesnt work

Comment: what if make title nullable?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `title` property is defined as non-nullable, but (apparently) is null or not present in the JSON.

In addition to that, the app is crashing because of the check the Kotlin compiler puts. You can see it in the stack trace:

```
method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter
```

This is because Gson (which I'm assuming you're using since you have `@SerializedName` annotations) uses Java reflection and ignores the nullability of the Kotlin type, so it will assign the field to null even if the Kotlin property is defined as non-nullable.

To solve the crash you'll have to define your property as nullable:

```kotlin
var title: String?
```

This way, the compiler will force you to add a null check before passing `title` to `saveTitleID`.

Answer (score 0):

try to nullable title in model

```
    data class Post(
    @SerializedName("products")
    var data: List<Data>,
    @SerializedName("productId")
    var productid: Int,
    @SerializedName("title")
    var title: String? = null
)
```